# How to programatically exit Xamarin Forms app without leave it running on second plan?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, terminate

I'm trying to close Xamarin Forms App from a logout button. However the code I find (example below) leaves the app in a second plan without terminate it completely.

```
Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
```

Is it possible to completely close the app without leave it running in a second plan? If so, please provide example code.

Comment: The above code looks android specific FYI

Answer (score 3):

There is no approved way of doing this. At the very least not for iOS. There are private APIs or workarounds but if your plan is to have your app in the App Store(s) it will never pass the review process.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You saved me some hours of research.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to make it work cross platform is by this command:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

However, Apple strongly discourages terminating apps. [From here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html).So suggest that not doing this in IOS.^.^